# How to authenticate user if password set as set_unusable_password()

Tags: python, django, api, authentication

I want to realize login for user with password which I set in models with help of **set_unusable_password**. I don't know how to realize authenticate for this user. Can I decode password which is record in db or can I realize my own authenticate function and after that use login(request, user)?

Method for creating user with unusable password:

```py
@staticmethod
    def create_user_via_facebook(first_name, last_name, userId):
        user = User(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, email=userId)
        user.set_unusable_password()
        user.save()
        return user
```

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to do here. Why are you setting an unusable password if you want to be able to authenticate?

Comment: I guess it's the creation of a user through Facebook authentication, hence the unusable password. My advice would be to use a library like social-auth-app-django to handle social logins.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll try to use it